# Subfunctor from a category to Set

Tags: category-theory, functors, forgetful-functors

I'm looking for the definition of a **subfunctor** $R$ of a functor $U:\cal K \to \mathbb {Set}$.
Are there any other conditions beyond that $R(A)\subseteq U(A)$ for all objects
$A\in \cal K$ ?

Comment: The correct definition would be a functor $R$ and a natural transformation $R\to U$ that is a monomorphism; that way it generalizes well. However, since $Set$ is complete, this amounts to the fact that each component is mono, and hence here injective. Thus you have a natural family of injections $R(A) \to U(A)$. Now its easy to show that $R$ will actually be naturally isomorphic to the functor of the images of these injections, so this comes down to the definition you gave

Comment: How does completeness of $\mathbb {Set}$ implies that components are exactly monos?

Comment: Because it implies that in the functor category, limits are computed pointwise : but you can characterize monos in terms of certain pullbacks

Answer (score 0):

On top of the condition that $R(A)\subseteq U(A)$ for every object $A$ in the category $\mathcal{K}$, you need the morphisms of $\mathcal{K}$ to behave accordingly: If $f:A\to B$ is a morphism in $\mathcal{K}$, then $R(f)$ should send $R(A)$ to $R(B)$. Since $R$ is a subfunctor of $U$, $R(f)$ is the restriction of $U(f)$ to the set $R(A)$, we may write this condition as
$$Uf[R(A)]\subseteq R(B).$$ Now remember that this should hold simultaneously for all the objects and morphisms in $\mathcal{K}$!